# no such column: api_task.content during makemigraions

Tags: python, django

When trying `./manage.py runserver` or `./manage.py makemigrations` or `./manage.py migrate` I am getting:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: api_task.content

All solutions say to

1. remove db.sqlite3
2. remove migrations folder
3. run `./manage.py makemigrations; ./manage.py migrate`

I did 1 and 2, but when trying to do 3 I get the error above (both commands, along with `./manage.py runserver`.

I am really confused as to why since, yes, it's obviously missing, but it should get recreated.

My aim was to clear the db, and since django recreates the db file, I should be able to just delete and make migrations, but I must be missing smth.

Task model:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Task(models.Model):
    id: str = models.UUIDField(
        unique=True,
        auto_created=True,
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    content: str = models.CharField(
        default="",
        max_length=255,
    )
    deadline: int = models.IntegerField(
        default=None,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    creationDate: models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    author: models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.id) + str(self.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

did you use the model in apps.py files?

if you wanna use the model in apps.py file, use below command:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
import sys

from django.db.models import Q


class AppTaskConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'app_task'

    def ready(self):
        # ---
        if "runserver" in sys.argv:
            from app_task.models import Task
            # ---
            # --- write your code with your model
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).